# Create an empty sorted set in Redis

Tags: redis, sortedset

Is there an easy way to create an empty sorted set in Redis? [The documentation](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) states

> If key does not exist, a new sorted set with the specified members as
>   sole members is created, like if the sorted set was empty. If the key
>   exists but does not hold a sorted set, an error is returned.

However, it does not say you can create an empty sorted set. The following doesn't create an empty sorted set:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd likes:0 1 one
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> exists likes:0
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zcard likes:0
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> dbsize
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrem likes:0 one
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> exists likes:0
(integer) 0
```

The use case is reliably migrating data from another database to Redis, namely Postgres:

1. When a post is created, create an empty sorted set `likes:<postId>`
2. When a like is created, perform a `zadd likes:<postId> <createdAt> <userId>` if `exists likes:<postId`. Otherwise, query Postgres for the likes, and store them in `likes:<postId>`.

Creating an empty sorted set enables the assertion which removes an excessive query to Postgres when the first like is made on that post, yet still supports posts that have not been migrated over to Redis yet. This optimization will save our database 100k+ reads per day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the key doesn't exist, it behaves as an empty instance of any type. In your case, you can avoid the call to `EXISTS likes:<postId>` and assume the key is there, because the resulting behavior will be the same: when you add a member, the list will be created if it didn't exist until that point.

Comment: This doesn't differ between the case where the list is empty because (1) it shouldn't have any data and (2) it hasn't been filled with data yet. The point of having `EXISTS likes:<postId>` return `1` for an empty, but initialized key, is to avoid having to query the persistent store again when it was done before anyways.

Comment: Maybe you want a bitmap of the ids you already migrated. You won't be able to use EXISTS on an empty list. Let me know if you want an explanation on how to use bitmaps for your use case.

Comment: Let's say you have a key called `migrated:posts`. You can use `SETBIT` and `GETBIT` to track if a post has been migrated. The command `SETBIT migrated:posts <postId> 1` will mark the post as migrated. To retrieve the value, use `GETBIT migrated:posts <postId>`. If you get a `1` it means it was migrated, otherwise you will get a `0`. Check those commands for more information, and feel free to ask me for clarifications.

Comment: @soveran lovin' it :)